# Що значать слова «власний» і «власне» і як вони відрізняються від слова «особистий»?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, різниця-між-словами

Чи правильно казати «власно, мені це не подобається» також як я б говорив «особисто, мені це не подобається.» Намагаюся перевести з Російської речення «лично, мне это не нравится». Також мені і в Російській не зовсім зрозуміло різниця між словами «лично» та «собственно».

Читав у словнику в Інтернеті що «власний» це те саме що «особистий». Чи «особисто» = «власно»? Будь ласка, поясніть мені різницю.

Іще, я читав у словнику в Інтернеті що «власне» може значити «по суті кажучи» або «якраз». Хтось може будь ласка мені дати приклади з реченням, включаючи це слово для обох значень?

Дякую.

Comment: Мабуть, правильніше «*перекласти* з російської», а не «перевести з російської». Також слово «російська» (так само як і слова «українська», «англійська» тощо) зазвичай пишуть з малої літери (хоча будь-яке слово в якихось особливих випадках можна написати з великої літери, наприклад, у знак поваги абощо, але звичайно назви мов пишуть з малої).

Comment: @Sasha дякую за поради

Comment: Я перепрошую за незакінчену відповідь. Я справді хочу її дописати і це значною мірою змінить її суть. Я «пінгану» Вас, коли закінчу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Недописана відповідь, допишу пізніше.

#### Прислівник «особисто» як частина словосполучення «особисто я»/«особисто ти»/тощо

Іншомовні:

> **Лично мне** это не нравится. [Рос.]
> **I personally** dislike that. **Personally, I** dislike that. [Англ.]

українською найчастіше перекладають як

> **Особисто мені** це не подобається. [[«СУМ-11»](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobysto), [«ГРАК-10»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Bword=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%8F%22%5D)]

(в українскій і російській кома *недоречна*, на відміну від англійської).

Приблизно те саме можна висловити й іншим чином, наприклад:

> **Персонально мені** це не подобається. [[«ГРАК-10»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Bword=%22(?i)%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%8F%22%5D)]
> **Мені самому** це не подобається. [[«ГРАК-10»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%8F%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%22%5D)]
> **Власне (власно) мені** це не подобається. [[«ГРАК-10»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Bword=%22(?i)%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%5B%D0%B5%D0%BE%5D%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%8F%22%5D)]

Жоден із цих варіантів не заборонений, хоче «персонально мені» і «власне (власно) мені» нині вживаються доволі рідко, а «мені самому» несе певну додаткову конотацію (наскільки я можу судити, чомусь на практиці «мені самому» часто використовується для порівняння з кимось, щось на зразок «мені, як і тобі» або, навпаки, «мені, на відміну від тебе»). (Знов повторюся, що кома зайва. У випадку з «власне (власно)» це критично, бо вставляння коми кардинально змінить значення речення.)

#### «Власне (кажучи)» як вставне слово(сполучення)

«Власне» («власно») [[СУМ-20](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15169&page=498)] часто вживається як вставне слово (коротший варіант вставного словосполучення «власне (власно) кажучи», що приблизно відповідає англійським «as a matter of fact», «properly/strictly speaking» і доволі чітко відповідає російському «собственно (говоря)»). У такому випадку воно відділяється паузами під час вимови, а на письмі — обов'язково комою (комами з обох боків, якщо в середині речення). Приклади з СУМ-20:

> Ні, се, **власне**, не було хвалою, але се більше варто було, ніж звичайне величання матірок своїми дочками (Леся Українка);
> Та ви, чоловіче добрий, чого ж, **власно**, прибігли до мене? Поділитись приємною новиною..? (В. Винниченко);
> **Власне кажучи**, по всіх п'єсах дядя Ваня грав самого себе (Ю. Яновський);
> Ці прізвища — Убийвовк, Підіпригора, Деришапка — давало козакам січове товариство (**власно кажучи**, це були прізвиська, які пізніше ставали прізвищами)
> (з навч. літ.).

Див. також [трапляння в ГРАК-10](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=(%3Cs%3E+%7C+%22,%22)+%22(?i)%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%5B%D0%B5%D0%BE%5D%22+%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%22?+(%3C/s%3E+%7C+%22,%22)&default_attr=word).

#### «Власний»/«власне (власно)» і «особистий»/«особисто»

Іменники:

- [Власність](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15175&page=498) — це речі, які комусь належить, або саме поняття приналежності речей людині (англ. propriety, рос. собственность).
- [Особистість](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobystistj) — це сама людина, але з погляду її рис, відмінностей від інших людей (англ. personality, рос. личность).

Можна було б спробувати сказати, що прикметник «власний» (рос. собственный, англ. own) — це протиставлення до «нічий» чи «чужий», а «особистий» (рос. личный, англ. personal) — до «публічний» чи «спільний». Хоча на практиці сфери вживання цих прикметників значною мірою перетинаються.

Але на відмінност…

---

<sub>Скорочення:

• СУМ-11 — [«Словник української мови» в 10 томах (1970-ті–1980-ті)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85);

• СУМ-20 — [«Словник української мови» у 20 томах (2010-ті–2020-ті)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85);

• ГРАК-10 — [«Генеральний регіонально анотований корпус української мови»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8), версія 10.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Тепер залишилося об'єднати ці дві відповіді. При цьому хочу переробити старішу.]

#### «Власність»/«власний»/«власне (власно)» і «особистість»/«особистий»/«особисто»

Іменники:

- [Власність](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15175&page=498) — це речі, які комусь належить, або саме поняття приналежності речей людині (англ. *ownership*, *property*, *propriety*, рос. *собственность*).
- [Особистість](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobystistj) — це сама людина, але з погляду її рис, відмінностей від інших людей (англ. *personality*, рос. *личность*).

Загалом не дуже правильно виводити значення іменників/прислівників від значень іменників (адже прямої відповідності може не бути), але тут, мені здається, значення прикметників значною мірою відповідають:

- *[Власний](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15170&page=498)* — це:

  1. Той, що належить (за правом власності) певній особі. Протилежність до *нічий* та *чужий*. Іншомовні відповідники: англ. *own*, рос. *собственный*.
  2. (Розширення попереднього значення) Той, з яким особа себе значною мірою асоціює; *рідний*. Наприклад, *власне місто* чи *власна країна* не обов'язково означають, що особа — надмагнат, якому належить усе місто чи країна, а радше що особа там народилася чи довго жила. Знов-таки, простилежне до *чужий* та відповідає англ. *own* і рос. *собственный*.
  3. У термінології деяких наук може позначати звичайний/типовий примірник (на противагу виродженому/тривіальному примірнику), відповідаючи англ. *proper*, наприклад: *власний дільник* (*proper divisor*), *власна підмножина* (*proper subset*) тощо. Але це доволі специфічна термінологія, до того ж вона часто має альтернативи (в інших підручниках пишуть *властивий* абощо).
- *[Особистий](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobystyj)* — це той, що стосується певної особи, а не всього колективу. Антоніми: *громадський*, *колективний*, *публічний*. Відповідники: англ. *personal* (також може бути *private*), рос. *личный*.

Сфери вживання прикметників *власний* і *особистий* значною мірою перетинаються.

*Власне* (*власно*) й *особисто*:

- [*Власне* (зрідка *власно*)](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15169&page=498) вважається часткою, відповідає рос. *собственно*, і, на мій погляд, як не дивно, хоча й бере щось від 1-го й 2-го значень прикметника *власний* (англ. *own*), але найближче саме до 3-го значення прикметника (англ. *proper*):

  1. Означає «буквально», «в прямому розумінні» (англ. *in proper meaning*, *literally*).
  2. Є скороченням від *власне кажучи* (англ. *properly speaking*).
  3. Також СУМ-20 каже, що це слово може використовуватися для підкреслення ролі когось чи чогось (наприклад, *я шукав власне Вас* — *I was looking exactly for you*, *власне Ви були причиною моїх проблем* — *it was you who caused my problems*), але, по-моєму, це специфічний частковий випадок 1-го значення.
- *[Особисто](http://sum.in.ua/s/osobysto)* загалом наслідує значення відповідного прикметника. Відповідає англ. *personally* і рос. *лично*. Зокрема використовується для того, щоб зазначити відсутність посередництва (англ. *at first hand*, *directly*, *immediately*).